# Question about select menus in bash

Tags: bash, scripts, menu

Before you tell me "there are tons of guides on this already" know that I actually have a select menu made and it is working.

However there is one thing that is driving me nuts. The way I have this menu coded currently this is what occurs:

1) User picks an option
2) Menu reloads
3) Option has an asterick next to it to show it is selected.

#### Problem:

The user has to select each option one at a time after the menu reloads after each selection. As you can imagine this is slow and make the terminal window messy.

#### What I want:

The user should be able to type 1-4 or 1,4,7 to select multiple options.

#### What I don't want:

A Whiptail or Dialog. I actually did make one as well and it is flawless. However I would prefer not to use it if I can help it or use it as a fallback. I think it would be more user friendly (not to mention easier on the eyes) to not use one.

#### Code:

```
#                           #
### CSGO Plugin selection ###
#                           #

options=(
         "SurfTimer - 2.02 - Core of this server."
         "AutoFileLoader - Caches all material, model, and sound files for players to download."
         "Chat-Procesor - Chat Processing Plugin"
         "Dynamic - PreReq for many plugins to work properly."
         "FixAngles - Fixes 'wrong angle on material' error that gets spammed in console when using store items"
         "Mapchooser_Extended - Map Vote System. See maplist.cfg/mapcycle.cfg.")
....


menu() {
    echo "Avaliable options:"
    for i in ${!options[@]}; do
        printf "%3d%s) %s\n" $((i+1)) "${choices[i]:- }" "${options[i]}"
    done
    [[ "$msg" ]] && echo "$msg"; :
}

prompt="Check an option (again to uncheck, ENTER when done): "
while menu && read -rp "$prompt" num && [[ "$num" ]]; do
    [[ "$num" != *[![:digit:]]* ]] &&
    (( num > 0 && num <= ${#options[@]} )) ||
    { msg="Invalid option: $num"; continue; }
    ((num--)); msg="${options[num]} was ${choices[num]:+un}checked"
    [[ "${choices[num]}" ]] && choices[num]="" || choices[num]="+"
done

printf "You selected"; msg=" nothing"
for i in ${!options[@]}; do
    [[ "${choices[i]}" ]] && { printf " %s" "${options[i]}"; msg=""; }
done
```

Comment: I wrote a little lime*rick*, to show you something printed **thick**, there is a char, looks like a star, the word you want is aste*risk*.

Comment: @dessert great. Are you gonna add anything meaningful to the discussion or are you just gonna correct people's grammar all day.

Comment: I can do both. *proud*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do it as follows:

```bsh
menu() {
    clear
    echo "Available options:"
    for i in ${!options[@]}; do
        printf "%3d%s) %s\n" $((i+1)) "${choices[i]:- }" "${options[i]}"
    done
}

prompt="Check an option (again to uncheck, ENTER when done): "
while menu && read -rp "$prompt" num && [[ "$num" ]]; do
    [[ "$num" =~ "-" ]] && num=$(seq $(sed -E 's/(\d*)-(\d*)/\1 \2/' <<<"$num"))
    for i in $num; do
      ((i--))
      [[ "${choices[i]}" ]] && choices[i]="" || choices[i]="*"
    done
done
```

This tests if `$num` contains a hyphen and builds the range if necessary, then simply loops over the content of `$num` so that users can give multiple options at once with e.g. `1 2 4` or `1-4` (but not a combination of those!). It also `clear`s the terminal every time before the menu is printed.

Comment: Flawless! Thank You! Although I am having trouble with the range. I am pretty new to bash so I could just be putting it in the wrong spot. I assume it should go right after the for loop but inside the while loop?

Comment: Hmm still not working. I did put it right before the for loop. But if you can't figure it out don't worry about it. You've already been a great help!

Comment: @Sandman007 Really? I edited it in, it works perfectly for me with `GNU bash 4.3.48(1)`…